# CXF maven plugin generate classes in wrong directory

Tags: maven-2, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm using maven cxf-codegen-plugin to generate java web service files from wsdl.
The plugin works fine if I'm trying to generate the files in the default output directory
(target\generated-sources\cxf), 
but if I'm trying to generate them in other directory by using:

```
<sourceRoot>src/main/myOtherDir</sourceRoot>
```

in my pom.xml,
the files are generated **only** if I do:

```
mvn clean eclipse:eclipse
```

If I do

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

without 'clean' the files are not generated...

Does anyone have any idea....?

My pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>src/main/myOtherDir</sourceRoot> 
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/AccountWS.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 3):

You are better off setting the sourceRoot below the target directory so it is cleaned along with other content, e.g.:

```
<sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
```

To ensure the plugin always executes, you need to bind it to a phase, e.g.

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>generate-sources</id>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    ...
    <goals>
      <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the problem, Very embarrassing...
Because I didn't update the wsdl, the plugin did not generate the files...

Anyway, the apache cfx documentation states that:
For CXF 2.1.4 and latter you don't need anymore to specify the `<phase>`, as generate-sources is the default.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I got into the same trouble. Delete the target directory and it will be re-generated.